# My every project build error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

My every project build error AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit since a week. I don't know why?

I tried almost every solution on internet.

I also reinstall my windows 10 and Android studio.

Still the same problem in my android studio.

Can anyone tell me what is the exact reason for this error?

This error not in any specific project. It is shown in all my projects even in my new hello world project.

Result of Run with --stack trace of the simple hello world project

Is below

```
   Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project C:\nnnnnnnnnnnn\MyApplication2

Task :clean Task :app:clean Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug Task :app:generateDebugResValues Task :app:generateDebugResources Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug Task :app:processDebugManifest Task :app:mergeDebugShaders Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE Task :app:mergeDebugAssets Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE Task :app:mergeDebugResources Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon. This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205) at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56) Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 1 exception was raised by workers: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$WorkerExecutorAdapter.await(Workers.kt:190) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:305) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:108) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.access$handleIncrementalInputs(IncrementalTask.kt:64) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:73) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:34) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle(IncrementalTask.kt:135) at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:568) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:553) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:536) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:276) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:265) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28) at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:192) ... 30 more Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:354) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:90) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:80) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:68) at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:258) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$WorkerExecutorAdapter.await(Workers.kt:188) ... 98 more Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon. This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does. at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:170) at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError$default(Aapt2Daemon.kt:168) at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:130) at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:175) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnableKt.processResources(Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable.kt:80) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:778) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.run(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:667) at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:242) at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50) at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:50) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59) at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44) at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36) at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:53) at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131) ... 3 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output:

at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl$WaitForTaskCompletion.err(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:312) at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl$processOutput$1.err(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:77) at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Comment: your sdk path, and your projects directory should not contain whitespace in names